# concatenating incrementing counter to string variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, string-concatenation

I have a script to create some files using format random_tests_0, random_tests_1
but my variable is not working when adding to the string of filename.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /A num=0
for %%a in (.\gpc_cfgs\*) do ( 
    ECHO !num!
    set filename = random_tests_!num!
    ECHO !filename!
    set /A num+=1
)
OUTPUT:
0
random_tests_0
1
random_tests_0

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
0
random_tests_0
1
random_tests_1
```

Comment: Try with `echo %num%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting a variable spaces either side of the `=` are included in both the name and the variable. *You should be able to fix that by using `!filename !` although the value would still begin with a possibly unwanted space too!*.

The recommended syntax is `Set "VariableName=VariableValue"`, thus:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "num=0"
For %%A In ("gpc_cfgs\*") Do (
    Echo !num!
    Set "filename=random_tests_!num!"
    Echo !filename!
    Set /A num+=1
)
```

This should output the same number of `!filenames!` as you have files inside `gpc_cfgs`.